# Am I misunderstanding NSUserDefaults initWithUser?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

**What I expect to happen:**

I create an NSUserDefaults object with a username (NSString of my choosing right?) and when I save defaults it saves those defaults for just that user.

**What actually happens:**

When I try creating NSUserDefaults for different usernames they are always saved into the same *com.companyname.appname.plist* file so it seems to ignore the per-user part and just save app-wide.

**My Question:**

Does this work on iOS or only OSX? What am I missing? Shouldn't I be getting a different plist file per-user? I reviewed the one .plist it does create in xcode and there's nothing in there that tells the default it belongs to a particular username.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you are misunderstanding it, but really it's a badly named method.

Essentially it's to allow Apps that run as root (or superuser) to access the UserDefaults for other users.

In this case, user is a unix user, not some arbitrary partitioning name that you (the developer) chooses.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure, NSUserDefaults is for a app, not a user. It is the defaults for that app. Now it is upto you to model it to store preferences for multiple users. Say using a NSDictionary

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults combines values from different sources.

If you use managed applications in the enterprise, there will be preferences coming from the enterprise device management system.

The application itself will have its own built-in defaults.

On top of that, the application can read and set applications per user; these are stored in the user's library/preferences.

If you do nothing unusual in your app, the preferences from all these sources will be combined, and whatever preferences you save will be stored as preferences for that particular user.

And as a very very unusual special case, apps running as root and not as a particular user can access *every* user's preferences.